# Quickblox iOS: Avoid call collision

Tags: ios, quickblox, videochat

I want to connect random users on a call (1 on 1 only) but that results sometimes in call collision. Steps that I took so far are:

1. On call button press I create a new session and try to connect with other users
2. The opponent users receives that call and has to accept or reject it, but in the meantime he is also waiting for accept/reject from the call that he made.

Basically everyone will end up calling someone and I am unable to think of a strategy where the system doesn't get overwhelmed with call requests.

Maybe someone who had a similar issue could help me with this problem